# How to find all possible daughters in a sequence of numbers stored in dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, search, dataframe

I have a python dataframe which one of its column such as `column1` contains series of numbers. I have to mention that each these numbers are the result of cell mutation so cell with number `n` deviates to two cells with following numbers: `2*n` and `2*n+1`. I want to search in this column to find all rows corresponds to daughters of specific number `k`. I mean the rows which contains all possible `{2*k, 2*k+1, 2*(2*k), 2*(2*k+1), ... }` in their `column1`. I don't want to use tree structure, how can I approach the solution ?  thanks

Comment: Can you please supply more terms of the series in terms of *k*?

Comment: Yes my columns is like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, ...where 1 corresponds to first cell. The first cell then differentiate to 2 and 3. Then 2 differenciates to 4 and 5 where 3 differentiate to 6 and 7. It mean that for number 2, I want to search between these items {4,5,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19 ,...} and for number 3 I want to search between these items {6,7,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,...}.

Comment: Thanks, I will need to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

The two sequences look like the numbers who's [binary expansion starts with `10`](http://oeis.org/A004754) and the numbers for which the [binary expansion starts with `11`](http://oeis.org/A004755).

Both sequences can be found directly:

```
import math

def f(n=2):
    while True:
        yield int(n + 2**math.floor(math.log(n,2)))
        n += 1

def g(n=2):
    while True:
        yield int(n + 2 * 2**math.floor(math.log(n,2)))
        n += 1

a, b = f(), g()
print [a.next() for i in range(15)]
print [b.next() for i in range(15)]
>>> [4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 32]
>>> [6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 48]
```

EDIT:

For an arbitrary starting point, you can do the following, which I think meets your criteria.

```
import Queue

def f(k):
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put(k)

    while not q.empty():
        p = q.get()
        a, b = 2*p, 2*p+1
        q.put(a)
        q.put(b)
        yield a
        yield b

a = f(4)
print [a.next() for i in range(16)]
>>> [8, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 64, 65] # ...

a = f(5)
print [a.next() for i in range(16)]
>>> [10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 23, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 80, 81] # ...
```

Checking those sequences against OEIS:

```
f(2) - Starting 10  - A004754
f(3) - Starting 11  - A004755
f(4) - Starting 100 - A004756
f(5) - Starting 101 - A004756
f(6) - Starting 110 - A004758
f(7) - Starting 111 - A004759
...
```

Which means you can simply do:

```
import math

def f(k, n=2):
    while True:
        yield int(n + (k-1) * 2**math.floor(math.log(n, 2)))
        n+=1

for i in range(2,8):
    a = f(i)
    print i, [a.next() for j in range(16)]

>>> 2 [4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 32]
>>> 3 [6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 48]
>>> 4 [8, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 64]
>>> 5 [10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 23, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 80]
>>> 6 [12, 13, 24, 25, 26, 27, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 96]
>>> 7 [14, 15, 28, 29, 30, 31, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 112]
# ... where the first number is shown for clarity.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to give the number and get its daughters. Your solution is based on having information about n, but unfortunately I don't have any information about the order of cell when it comes to bigger number stored in df. I need specify number "k" and get all possible daughters 2*k and 2*k+1.

Comment: Can you give an example for larger `k`?

Comment: because it is a cell number during cell generation it takes numbers like 6842 sometimes.

Comment: And the series become what?

Comment: It will stop at some point, I have to check it by myself for example consider the depth of daughters less than 1000.

Comment: @Thanks a lot, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but seems to work alright. What I think you might have needed to know is the newer `yield from` construction. Used twice in this code. Never thought I would.

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import count

def daughters(k):
    print ('daughters of cell', k)
    if k<=0:
        return
    if k==1:
        yield from count(1)

    def locateK():
        cells = 1
        newCells = 2
        generation = 1
        while True:
            generation += 1
            previousCells = cells
            cells += newCells 
            newCells *= 2
            if k > previousCells and k <= cells :
                break
        return ( generation, k - previousCells )

    parentGeneration, parentCell = locateK()

    cells = 1
    newCells = 2
    generation = 1
    while True:
        generation += 1
        previousCells = cells
        if generation > parentGeneration:
            if parentCell%2:
                firstChildCell=previousCells+int(Fraction(parentCell-1, 2**parentGeneration)*newCells)+1
            else:
                firstChildCell=previousCells+int(Fraction(parentCell, 2**parentGeneration)*newCells)+1
            yield from range(firstChildCell, firstChildCell+int(newCells*Fraction(1,2)))
        cells += newCells
        newCells *= 2

for n, d in enumerate(daughters(2)):
    print (d)
    if n > 15:
        break
```

Couple of representative results:

```
daughters of cell 2
4
5
8
9
10
11
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
32
33
34


daughters of cell 3
6
7
12
13
14
15
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
48
49
50
```

Comment: Thanks Bill,but  this is exactly my problem which I don't know how to generate both of children each time.  I need '2*k+1' as well, but if you trace the result you can see 13, 15 , ... aren't there for '2*6+1' and '2*7+1'.

Comment: That's why I wrote 'something like this'. :) I wasn't clear about what you mean.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14608765)

Comment: @GregGlockner: Pls look again. Was just stalling for some time.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that you put so much effort on it, it would help me a lot.

Comment: `@GregGlockner`, it can be annoying when people criticize or downvote an answer that is in progress.  If the problem is complicated enough we need time and space to think and dialog.  The comment space often isn't enough.

Comment: You're very welcome! I couldn't give up on it. Quite interesting.

Comment: @hpaulj: Although I agree with you Mr Glockner was acting as a reviewer. We must forgive him.